# How to find index of substring displayed in resizeable/scrolling textbox?

Tags: c#, string, textbox, indexing

I'm planning a C# app where some rather large strings will be displayed in scrollable/resizeable textboxes.

When the user closes the app and returns later, I'd like to redisplay these strings from the point they were displayed on `lostFocus`.

Is there a way to get the index, within the full text, of the first char that is displayed in a textBox?

Comment: You should tag this with WPF, Silverlight or Winforms so it's easier to know which TextBox you're using :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These two should help you get the caret position. Get the caret position before you close your application, and then set it back using the `SelectionStart` property:

```
textBox1.SelectionStart;
textBox1.SelectionLength;
```

**EDIT:**
This works, just tested, as I said, it is important to use `SelectionStart` property and `ScrollToCaret()` method. You will have to get the index of the char that is first visible, for this you should use `GetCharIndexFromPosition()` method from the `TextBox`:

```
        int selectionStart;

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Graphics g = textBox1.CreateGraphics();
            SizeF size = g.MeasureString("A", textBox1.Font);
            g.Dispose();
            int index = textBox1.GetCharIndexFromPosition(new Point(0, (int)(2 * size.Height + 0.5)));
            selectionStart = index;
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.SelectionStart = selectionStart;
            textBox1.ScrollToCaret();
        }
```

Comment: Who said the text was selected?

Comment: @khellang you don't have to have selected text to get the caret postition this way, The SelectionLength is then 0 but SelectionStart holds the caret position. Have you tried to use it? What if he is using winforms?

Comment: I know `SelectionStart` indicates the caret position when no text is selected, but the caret doesn't follow the scroll position...

Comment: @khellang Are you satisfied with the answer now?

Comment: Hehe, OK. If you say it works.. We'll let @user1793659 decide :)

Comment: Thanks a lot, Nick!
GetCharIndexFromPosition() is what I needed. Quite obvious once you know it... Indeed, there's no selected text. Just a large text (which might be a few pages long) that the user might appreciate if it's re-displayed from the same point as when the app was closed.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't get your question, but upto my understanding

`TextBox.CaretIndex` will solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using WPF or Silverlight; The `System.Windows.Controls.TextBox` has a method [`TextBox.GetFirstVisibleLineIndex()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.getfirstvisiblelineindex%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).
Use this in combination with the [`MaxLines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.maxlines%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [`MinLines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.minlines%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) properties to save the state.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all!

I guess that Nick just solved it (Thanks!).
GetCharIndexFromPosition() is the way to go.
I had read about that function call but I had no idea about how to create a Point object referencing the first "insertion point" in the TextBox.

Kind regards,

JPeraita